# I am not getting the value onchange of togglebuttongroup material ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, togglebutton

I am using togglebuttongroup of material ui. But on change ebent, I am not 
   able to get the value of selected tab. Also I am not able to get the 
   target. When I click on the button, I get target as  which is not 
   right.

``````````````````````````````
``````````
 <FormControlLabel 
          margin="normal"
          label="Private ?   "
          labelPlacement="start"
              control={
               <div style={{paddingTop : 10, paddingLeft: 20}} >
                <ToggleButtonGroup 
                    name = 'isprivate'
                    className = "tglebtngrp" 
                    value={this.state.isprivate}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}>
                  <ToggleButton value="Yes">
                      Yes
                  </ToggleButton>
                   <ToggleButton value="No">
                      No
                  </ToggleButton>
                </ToggleButtonGroup>
                </div>
              } /> 

  On Change function:
```````````````````````
    handleChange = (event) => {
   console.log(event.target);
    this.setState({[event.target.name] : event.target.value});
    console.log(this.state);
    }
`````````````````````````````
``````````````````````````````

Also I need to show the tab selected. So I tried doing this.

``````````````````````
`````````````
  <ToggleButton className={this.state.isprivate=='Yes' ? 
   classes.active_tab :classes.default_tabStyle}  
                     value="Yes"> 

   CSS:
        default_tabStyle:{
        color: 'black',
        fontSize:11,
       backgroundColor: 'blue',
        },

      active_tabStyle:{
        fontSize:11,
          color: 'white',
        backgroundColor: 'red',
     },
`````````````````````
``````````````````````

Comment: Please create a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) reproducing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using the example of the [react website](https://material-ui.com/components/toggle-button/) you can get the value through a parameter in the (your) handleChange function.

First you have a const:

```
const [alignment, setAlignment] = React.useState("left");
```

Then you can use this const in your html code like here (line 3):

```
<div className={classes.toggleContainer}>
      <ToggleButtonGroup
        value={alignment}
        exclusive
        onChange={handleAlignment}
      >
        <ToggleButton value="left">
          <FormatAlignLeftIcon />
        </ToggleButton>
        <ToggleButton value="center">
          <FormatAlignCenterIcon />
        </ToggleButton>
        <ToggleButton value="right">
          <FormatAlignRightIcon />
        </ToggleButton>
        <ToggleButton value="justify" disabled>
          <FormatAlignJustifyIcon />
        </ToggleButton>
      </ToggleButtonGroup>
    </div>
```

With the function handleAlignment (line 5) you can change and get the current value.

```
const handleAlignment = (event, newAlignment) => {
    setAlignment(newAlignment);
    console.log(newAlignment);
};
```

Depending on how your togglebuttons are set up you will get one value (Exclusive selection i.e. tabs) or an array of values (Mulitple selection)

[image]

A working example you can find in [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-4773b?fontsize=14).

Comment: There should now be **just 1** param to `handleChange`, no `event`, just `newRealignment`. Otherwise it doesn't work anymore.